# Checksum 0xDEAD in TCP ACK

Tags: networking, tcp

I am seeing in the network traces, that my client is sending the following ACK frame to the DC:


`Frame: Number = 87641, Captured Frame Length = 54, MediaType = ETHERNET

+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA],SourceAddress:[AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA]

+ Ipv4: Src = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(CLIENT), Dest = YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY, Next Protocol = TCP, Packet ID = 26829, Total IP Length = 40

- Tcp:  [Bad CheckSum]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=14229, DstPort=LDAP(389), PayloadLen=0, Seq=4175359382, Ack=1985975784, Win=1357

-   SrcPort: 14229

-   DstPort: LDAP(389)

-   SequenceNumber: 4175359382 (0xF8DEED96)

-    AcknowledgementNumber: 1985975784 (0x765F95E8)

  + DataOffset: 80 (0x50)

  + Flags: ...A....

-    Window: 1357

-    Checksum: 0xDEAD, Bad

-    UrgentPointer: 0 (0x0)`

Is the Checksum 0xDEAD an indication of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP packet checksums have no special meaning, even if their hex representations spell an English word.  If the packets with a bad check-sum are a common occurrence, you should investigate the source of the packets... often running TCP offload on your NIC will break the checksums passed to the sniffer (if TCP Offload is on the NIC doing the sniffing)... however, as a general rule, bad TCP checksums could also indicate a faulty driver, faulty software, or possibly malicious activity...

As a side note, faulty ethernet frame checksums may indicate a bad NIC, bad cable, or possible malicious activity as well.